# Index is getting multiplied automatic

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am trying to implement a feature where users can shop a car buy purchasing but the issue I am facing is the car index is getting multiplied automatically, and disappears when the index is out of range.

In screenshot 1 check on the console, I am at index one of the car.

[image]

In second screenshot When I click on buy this car the car index jumps to index 3:

[image]

And it's getting multiplied if I click again on the buy this car button the index will be multiplied by the last index if the index is on 3 it will be 3*3 and if it's 6 then 6*6.

Here is the code:

```
public class SelectCars : MonoBehaviour
{
// Start is called before the first frame update

public static SelectCars instance;
[SerializeField] Button PrevButton;
[SerializeField] Button NextButton;
[SerializeField] Button UseButton;
[SerializeField] GameObject BuyPanel;
public Button BuyButton,closePanelButton, BuyDiamonds;

int CurrentCar,haveCoins,haveDiamonds;
int carValue = 700;
int addDiamonds;
[Header("Buy Panel")]
public Text haveCoinsText, haveDiamondsText,moreStarNeedText;

string ownCarIndex;
Color RedColor = new Color(1f, 0.1f, 0.1f,1f);
Color GreenColor = new Color(0.5f, 1f, 0.4f,1f);


void Awake()
{
    ChangeCar(0);
     if(instance == null)
     {
        instance = this;
     }

}
void Start()
{
    Application.targetFrameRate = Screen.currentResolution.refreshRate;
    haveCoins =    PlayerPrefs.GetInt("totalCoins",haveCoins);
    haveDiamonds = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("totalDiamonds",haveDiamonds);

}

// Update is called once per frame




public void ChooseCar(int _index)
{
    PrevButton.interactable = (_index != 0);
    NextButton.interactable = (_index != transform.childCount - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < transform.childCount; i++)  //it will count all child cars by using transform.childCount
    {
        string carNo = "CarNo" + i;
        if(i == 0)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt(carNo,1);
        }
        transform.GetChild(i).gameObject.SetActive(i == _index);
    }
}


public void ChangeCar(int _change)
{
    CurrentCar += _change;
    ChooseCar(CurrentCar);
    ownCarIndex = "CarNo" + CurrentCar;
    Debug.Log(ownCarIndex);
    if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt(ownCarIndex) == 1)
    {
        UseButton.GetComponent<Image>().color = GreenColor;
        UseButton.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = "Select";
    }
    else
    {
        UseButton.GetComponent<Image>().color = RedColor;
        UseButton.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = "Buy Now";
    }
}


public void UsetBtnClick()
{
    if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt(ownCarIndex) == 1)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("SelectCar",CurrentCar);
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Game");
    }else
    {
        BuyPanel.SetActive(true);
        PrevButton.interactable = false;
        NextButton.interactable = false;
        UseButton.interactable = false;

        haveCoinsText.text = "You Have " + haveCoins + " Coims";
        haveDiamondsText.text = "You Have " + haveDiamonds + " Diamonds";
        if (haveCoins < carValue)
        {
            int needStar = carValue - haveCoins;
            BuyButton.interactable = false;
            moreStarNeedText.text = "You Need " + needStar + " Coins To Buy";
        }
        else
        {
            BuyButton.interactable = true;
            moreStarNeedText.color = GreenColor;
            moreStarNeedText.text = "You can buy this car";
        }
        
    }
}


public void BuyDiamond()
{
    if(haveCoins < 100)
    {
        BuyDiamonds.interactable = false;
    }else
    {
        haveDiamonds += 1;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("totalDiamonds", haveDiamonds);
        haveDiamondsText.text = "You Have " + haveDiamonds + " Diamonds";

        haveCoins -= 100;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("totalCoins", haveCoins);
        haveCoinsText.text = "You Have " + haveCoins + " Coins";



        
    }
}

public void EarnCoins()
{
    haveCoins += 100;
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("totalCoins", haveCoins);
    haveCoinsText.text = "You Have " + haveCoins + " Coins";
}



public void ClosePanel()
{
    BuyPanel.SetActive(false);
    PrevButton.interactable = true;
    NextButton.interactable = true;
    UseButton.interactable = true;
}

public void BuyThisCar()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt(ownCarIndex,1);
    haveCoins += -carValue;
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("totalCoins", haveCoins);
    int currentMinOne = CurrentCar - 1;
    ChangeCar(currentMinOne);
    ClosePanel();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `ChangeCar` function accepts an index but is using `+=` instead of `=`:

```
public void ChangeCar(int _change)
{
    CurrentCar += _change;  // This should probably be =
```

Also, when you call it from `BuyThisCar()`, you're subtracting `1` from the current index but aren't making sure that the result isn't > 0:

```
public void BuyThisCar()
{
   ...
   int currentMinOne = CurrentCar - 1;
   // You must make sure currentMinOne is > 0 before sending it to ChangeCar
   ChangeCar(CurrentCar);
```

Comment: Sorry i just changed the code instead of ChangeCar(CurrentCar); I added ChangeCar(currentMinOne);
But i am still getting the same error.
One more thing if I remove this code "ChangeCar(CurrentCar);" and when I play the game the car index doesn't gets multiplied but the buy now text don't change to select now

anyways I am following this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FryfvFXWPtw&themeRefresh=1